# Ubuntu 18.04: Synaptics Fingerprint Reader On HP Spectre not working

Tags: 18.04, hp, fingerprint-reader

FP driver not working; tried Fingerprint-GUI with no luck.

```
~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bb Synaptics, Inc.
```

[image: Fingerprint-GUI screenshot attached]